# Max number of sub folders

Tags: multisite, directory

I have a fairly trivial question. What is the max number of subdirectories in WordPress?

We are planning to move our current website to WordPress and I have been told that you can have, at most, 2 levels to subdirectories.

Typically, you can only have /{category}/{tag}/page_content
Where {category} and {tag} are (as their name mention) the categories and tags of the page_content page.

Is there a way to have a url like /pages_content_1/pages_content_2/page_content_3/page_content_4, where all page_content_x actually have content?

I came across the following link (http://smallbusiness.chron.com/move-wordpress-root-subfolder-52605.html), but it doesn't really address my case.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean nested pages?

```
pages_content_1 (page with content, parent↓)
  pages_content_2 (page with content, child of above, parent↓) 
    pages_content_3 (page with content, child of above, parent↓) 
      pages_content_4 (page with content, child of above)
```

If so, I don't believe there is a limit. The URL would be

```
http://example.com/pages_content_1/pages_content_2/pages_content_3/pages_content_4
```

I'm not sure what you mean by `/{category}/{tag}/page_content`, WordPress does not typically permalink in this fashion.

Comment: Yes. I do mean nested pages as per your scheme